# catkin_make error: Built target move_base_node

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm  new to Ubuntu and ROS.

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
ROS distribution: kinetic

Whenever I type

```
catkin_make
```

I get the following terminal output stopping at [93%] Built target move_base_node:

```
moro01@mach-moro01:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/moro01/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/moro01/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/moro01/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/moro01/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/moro01/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/moro01/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target snap7_ros_interface_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target snap7_ros_interface_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target snap7_ros_interface_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target snap7_ros_interface_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target snap7_ros_interface_generate_messages_lisp
[  1%] Built target realsense2_camera_gencfg
[  1%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target ps4_ros
[  2%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target _realsense2_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_IMUInfo
[  2%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  2%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target _realsense2_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_Extrinsics
[  2%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target _catkin_empty_exported_target
[  2%] Built target bond_generate_messages_py
[  2%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[  2%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_py
[  2%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[  2%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_gencfg
[  2%] Built target tf_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_py
[  2%] Built target bond_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target bond_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target bond_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target bond_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  3%] Built target tf_listener
[  4%] Built target tf_broadcaster
[  4%] Built target sick_scan_gencfg
[  5%] Built target pcl_converter
[  5%] Built target _sick_scan_generate_messages_check_deps_RadarObject
[  5%] Built target _sick_scan_generate_messages_check_deps_RadarPreHeaderEncoderBlock
[  5%] Built target _sick_scan_generate_messages_check_deps_RadarScan
[  5%] Built target _sick_scan_generate_messages_check_deps_RadarPreHeader
[  5%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  5%] Built target _sick_scan_generate_messages_check_deps_RadarPreHeaderDeviceBlock
[  5%] Built target _sick_scan_generate_messages_check_deps_RadarPreHeaderMeasurementParam1Block
[  5%] Built target _sick_scan_generate_messages_check_deps_RadarPreHeaderStatusBlock
[  5%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_py
[  5%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_lisp
[  5%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_nodejs
[  5%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_eus
[  5%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_eus
[  5%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_cpp
[  5%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_py
[  5%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  5%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  5%] Built target pcl_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  5%] Built target pcl_ros_gencfg
[  5%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  5%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_lisp
[  5%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_cpp
[  5%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  5%] Built target nodelet_topic_tools_gencfg
[  5%] Built target pcl_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  5%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  5%] Built target pcl_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  5%] Built target pcl_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  7%] Built target amcl_pf
[  7%] Built target pcl_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  8%] Built target amcl_gencfg
[ 10%] Built target amcl_map
[ 11%] Built target voxel_grid
[ 12%] Built target fake_localization
[ 12%] Built target map_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 12%] Built target map_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 12%] Built target map_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 12%] Built target map_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 14%] Built target costmap_2d_gencfg
[ 14%] Built target map_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 14%] Built target _costmap_2d_generate_messages_check_deps_VoxelGrid
[ 15%] Built target base_local_planner_gencfg
[ 16%] Built target dwa_local_planner_gencfg
[ 16%] Built target _base_local_planner_generate_messages_check_deps_Position2DInt
[ 16%] Built target global_planner_gencfg
[ 16%] Built target _navfn_generate_messages_check_deps_SetCostmap
[ 16%] Built target _navfn_generate_messages_check_deps_MakeNavPlan
[ 16%] Built target move_base_gencfg
[ 16%] Built target move_base_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 16%] Built target move_base_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 16%] Built target move_base_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 16%] Built target move_base_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 16%] Built target move_base_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 16%] Built target teb_local_planner_gencfg
[ 16%] Built target costmap_converter_generate_messages_cpp
[ 16%] Built target _teb_local_planner_generate_messages_check_deps_TrajectoryPointMsg
[ 16%] Built target costmap_converter_generate_messages_py
[ 16%] Built target _teb_local_planner_generate_messages_check_deps_FeedbackMsg
[ 16%] Built target _teb_local_planner_generate_messages_check_deps_TrajectoryMsg
[ 16%] Built target costmap_converter_generate_messages_lisp
[ 16%] Built target costmap_converter_generate_messages_eus
[ 16%] Built target costmap_converter_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 16%] Built target map_server_image_loader
[ 16%] Built target snap7_ros_interface_generate_messages
[ 17%] Built target map_server-map_saver
[ 18%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_lisp
[ 19%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_cpp
[ 20%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_eus
[ 21%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_py
[ 22%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 28%] Built target sick_scan_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 28%] Built target sick_scan_generate_messages_eus
[ 31%] Built target sick_scan_generate_messages_py
[ 34%] Built target sick_scan_generate_messages_cpp
[ 36%] Built target sick_scan_generate_messages_lisp
[ 38%] Built target amcl_sensors
[ 38%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages_eus
[ 39%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages_cpp
[ 40%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages_lisp
[ 40%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 41%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages_py
[ 41%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages_cpp
[ 42%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages_py
[ 42%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 43%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages_eus
[ 43%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages_lisp
[ 43%] Built target navfn_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 44%] Built target navfn_generate_messages_cpp
[ 45%] Built target navfn_generate_messages_py
[ 46%] Built target navfn_generate_messages_eus
[ 47%] Built target teb_local_planner_generate_messages_cpp
[ 48%] Built target navfn_generate_messages_lisp
[ 49%] Built target teb_local_planner_generate_messages_py
[ 50%] Built target teb_local_planner_generate_messages_lisp
[ 52%] Built target teb_local_planner_generate_messages_eus
[ 53%] Built target teb_local_planner_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 53%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages
[ 54%] Built target map_server
[ 54%] Built target sick_scan_generate_messages
[ 54%] Built target amcl
[ 54%] Building CXX object realsense/realsense2_camera/CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/src/base_realsense_node.cpp.o
[ 60%] Built target sick_scan_lib
[ 64%] Built target costmap_2d
[ 64%] Built target costmap_2d_generate_messages
[ 64%] Built target base_local_planner_generate_messages
[ 64%] Built target navfn_generate_messages
[ 64%] Built target teb_local_planner_generate_messages
[ 66%] Built target sick_generic_caller
[ 67%] Built target radar_object_marker
[ 69%] Built target sick_scan_test
[ 70%] Built target costmap_2d_markers
[ 70%] Built target costmap_2d_node
[ 70%] Built target costmap_2d_cloud
[ 72%] Built target layers
[ 73%] Built target point_grid
[ 74%] Built target clear_costmap_recovery
[ 75%] Built target move_slow_and_clear
[ 82%] Built target base_local_planner
[ 83%] Built target navfn
[ 84%] Built target trajectory_planner_ros
[ 85%] Built target navfn_node
[ 88%] Built target global_planner
[ 89%] Built target carrot_planner
[ 89%] Built target rotate_recovery
[ 90%] Built target dwa_local_planner
[ 91%] Built target planner
[ 92%] Built target move_base
[ 92%] Building CXX object teb_local_planner/CMakeFiles/teb_local_planner.dir/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp.o
[ 93%] Built target move_base_node
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/realsense/realsense2_camera/src/base_realsense_node.cpp: In lambda function:
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/realsense/realsense2_camera/src/base_realsense_node.cpp:643:56: error: ‘class rs2::processing_block’ has no member named ‘process’
                         frameset = filter_it->_filter->process(frameset);
                                                        ^
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool teb_local_planner::TebLocalPlannerROS::computeVelocityCommands(geometry_msgs::Twist&)’:
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp:229:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS::getRobotPose(tf::Stamped<tf::Transform>&)’
   costmap_ros_->getRobotPose(robot_pose);
                                        ^
In file included from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/navigation/nav_core/include/nav_core/base_local_planner.h:42:0,
                 from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/include/teb_local_planner/teb_local_planner_ros.h:45,
                 from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp:39:
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/navigation/costmap_2d/include/costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h:125:8: note: candidate: bool costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS::getRobotPose(geometry_msgs::PoseStamped&) const
   bool getRobotPose(geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& global_pose) const;
        ^
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/navigation/costmap_2d/include/costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h:125:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘tf::Stamped<tf::Transform>’ to ‘geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& {aka geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >&}’
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp:234:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘base_local_planner::OdometryHelperRos::getRobotVel(tf::Stamped<tf::Transform>&)’
   odom_helper_.getRobotVel(robot_vel_tf);
                                        ^
In file included from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/include/teb_local_planner/teb_local_planner_ros.h:47:0,
                 from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp:39:
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/navigation/base_local_planner/include/base_local_planner/odometry_helper_ros.h:66:8: note: candidate: void base_local_planner::OdometryHelperRos::getRobotVel(geometry_msgs::PoseStamped&)
   void getRobotVel(geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& robot_vel);
        ^
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/navigation/base_local_planner/include/base_local_planner/odometry_helper_ros.h:66:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘tf::Stamped<tf::Transform>’ to ‘geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& {aka geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >&}’
realsense/realsense2_camera/CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'realsense/realsense2_camera/CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/src/base_realsense_node.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [realsense/realsense2_camera/CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/src/base_realsense_node.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3819: recipe for target 'realsense/realsense2_camera/CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [realsense/realsense2_camera/CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp:46:0,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/class_loader/class_loader.hpp:43,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/class_loader/./multi_library_class_loader.hpp:42,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/class_loader/multi_library_class_loader.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/pluginlib/class_loader.hpp:38,
                 from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/navigation/costmap_2d/include/costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h:50,
                 from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/navigation/nav_core/include/nav_core/base_local_planner.h:42,
                 from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/include/teb_local_planner/teb_local_planner_ros.h:45,
                 from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp:39:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/class_loader/meta_object.hpp: In instantiation of ‘B* class_loader::class_loader_private::MetaObject<C, B>::create() const [with C = teb_local_planner::TebLocalPlannerROS; B = nav_core::BaseLocalPlanner]’:
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp:1159:1:   required from here
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/class_loader/meta_object.hpp:198:16: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘teb_local_planner::TebLocalPlannerROS’
     return new C;
                ^
In file included from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp:39:0:
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/include/teb_local_planner/teb_local_planner_ros.h:92:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘teb_local_planner::TebLocalPlannerROS’:
 class TebLocalPlannerROS : public nav_core::BaseLocalPlanner
       ^
In file included from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/include/teb_local_planner/teb_local_planner_ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/teb_local_planner/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp:39:
/home/moro01/catkin_ws/src/navigation/nav_core/include/nav_core/base_local_planner.h:78:20: note:   virtual void nav_core::BaseLocalPlanner::initialize(std::__cxx11::string, tf2_ros::Buffer*, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS*)
       virtual void initialize(std::string name, tf2_ros::Buffer* tf, costmap_2d
                    ^
teb_local_planner/CMakeFiles/teb_local_planner.dir/build.make:230: recipe for target 'teb_local_planner/CMakeFiles/teb_local_planner.dir/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [teb_local_planner/CMakeFiles/teb_local_planner.dir/src/teb_local_planner_ros.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:10314: recipe for target 'teb_local_planner/CMakeFiles/teb_local_planner.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [teb_local_planner/CMakeFiles/teb_local_planner.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

I know there seem to be multiple errors and if a seperate question for each error is wished I'll gladly do so.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328663/catkin_make-error:-built-target-move_base_node/) by [Daniel_](https://answers.ros.org/users/44069/daniel_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2019-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The predecessor I got the project from used some old realsense package. Getting both the new realsense-ros package and the therefore needed ddynamic_reconfigure both from github fixed the realsense related issues.

As for the teb errors. My predecessor pretty much built everything from source and since this project is my first contact with ros and ubuntu I had no idea that this isn't needed often. So I first tried to built teb from source too which didn't work. After removing it from my workspace and doing `catkin_make clean`, there were still teb related files in both devel and build directories. Deleting those solved all issues.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel_](https://answers.ros.org/users/44069/daniel_/) with karma: 51 on 2019-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-01**:
Thanks for reporting back with your solution.

> My predecessor pretty much built everything from source and [..] I had no idea that this isn't needed often.

Indeed. This is something many (beginning) users get wrong: there is often no need to build things from sources. It should be avoided if at all possible: wasteful of resources (CPU and your time) and can lead to all sorts of hard-to-diagnose problems.